# EX of Ordered random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given $X_1$,...,$X_n$ independent variables with the same density $f(x)=λe^{-λx} , x>0$ how do we calculate the $EX_{(1)}$, $EX_{(n)}$ and $EX_{(1)}X_{(n)}$ ?
It is known that the desity of $X_{(1)}$ is:

$$f_1(x)=n(1-F(x))^{n-1}f(x), x>0$$

where $F(x)=1-e^{-λx}, x>0$ and the joint desity of $X_{(1)}$, $X_{(n)}$ is :

$$f_{1n}(x,y)=n(n-1)λ^2e^{-λ(x+y)}(e^{-λx} -e^{-λy})^{n-2},x<y$$

I have only managed to calculate that $EX_{(1)}=(\frac{1}{nλ})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the same principle.   The density function of the $k$ order statistic of $n$ independent samples of continuous random variable $X$ is:

$$f_{X_{(k)}}(x) =\dfrac{n!~F_X(x)^{k-1}~f_X(x)~(1-F_X(x))^{n-k}}{(k-1)!~1!~(n-k)!}$$

And jointly:$$f_{X_{(j)},X_{(k)}}(x,y) = \dfrac{n!~F_X(x)^{j-1}~f_X(x)~(F_X(y)-F_X(x))^{k-j-1}~f_X(y)~(1-F_X(y))^{n-k}}{(j-1)!1!(k-j-1)!1!(n-k)!}$$

---

So $$\begin{align}f_{X_{(1)}}(x) ~=~&\dfrac{n!~F_X(x)^{1-1}~f_X(x)~(1-F_X(x))^{n-1}}{(1-1)!~(n-1)!}\\ =~& n f_X(x)~(1-F_X(x))^{n-1} \\ =~& n\lambda e^{-n\lambda x}\end{align}$$

Thus $\mathsf E(X)=\int_0^\infty n\lambda x e^{-n\lambda x}\operatorname d x=1$

---

$$\begin{align}f_{X_{(n)}}(x) ~=~&\dfrac{n!~F_X(x)^{n-1}~f_X(x)~(1-F_X(x))^{n-n}}{(n-1)!~(n-n)!}\\ =~& n F_X(x)^{n-1}~f_X(x) \\ =~& n (1-e^{-\lambda x})^{n-1}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} \\ =~& n\lambda \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(-1)^r\binom{n-1}{r}e^{-(1+r)\lambda x}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X_{(n)}) ~=~& \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(-1)^r\binom{n-1}{r}\int_0^\infty n\lambda xe^{-(1+r)\lambda x}\operatorname d x\\ ~=~& \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}(-1)^r\binom{n-1}{r}\dfrac n{\lambda (r+1)^2}\end{align}$$

et cetera...

Comment: @wolfies  Complain to the site admin if the problem persists.